# How to select list item by its contents?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'd like to know how to write a CSS rule for list element by its contents:

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li>first item</li>
  <li>empty</li>
  <li>second item</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I'd like to have a rule for `li` containing *empty*. I can create javascript sniffing innerHTML of childNodes, but I wonder if there is a plain CSS solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Answer is No... there is no logic or string manipulation routines in css BUT if you could add a class to the li containing 'empty' then its easy

Comment: i.e. If you are generating the li using javascript/server side language then just add a class to the `<li class="empty">empty</li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was asking a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029001/adblock-plus-filter-how-to-select-element-by-its-child-contents) a few months ago. It seems you can not check the contents of elements, so **no**. Stay with the javascript.

Comment: Okay I will. At least I know it is not a bad approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like text selector in CSS yet, CSS is not a programming language, it doesn't know what's inside the element, that's where JavaScript and jQuery comes in.

You can use jQuery `:contains()` selector instead(Yea I know you wanted CSS but that is not possiblehere)

If you don't use the word `empty` literally and if you are referring to an empty element, than you can use `:empty` selector to select elements which are empty

Comment: CSS just doesn't know about the text content of an element. It has nothing to do with CSS not being a programming language.

Comment: @BoltClock I was just pointing that as jQuery can peep in, CSS cannot

Answer (score 0):

There is an `:empty` selector you could use. It matches every element that has no children (including text nodes).

```
p:empty {
  /* p tags that are empty */
}
```

Mozilla Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:empty

> The :empty pseudo-class represents any element that has no children at all. Only element nodes and text (including whitespace) are considered. Comments or processing instructions do not affect whether an element is considered empty or not.

Comment: This is useful, but I really need to check the contents.

Comment: Then refer to @Mr. Alien answer